# Bash redirect stderr and stdout to function stops execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this bash script, where i have a function called LogMsg which I use to log all output of several commands to a single file.

However, when I try to redirect to stderr and stdout from another bash script, only the first line is logged, and the rest of the script seems to not be run (the script called in my bash file).

```
#!/bin/bash
#Contains all executions for backup jobs

function LogMsg {
    now="$(date +'%d/%m/%Y %T')"
    if [ -n "$1" ]
    then
        IN="$1"
    else
        read IN
    fi
    echo "$now [LOG]: $IN" >> $LOG_FILE;
}

LogMsg "Starting backup procedure"
LogMsg "Dumping MongoDB databases"

/bin/bash /root/mongodump.sh 2>&1 | LogMsg

LogMsg "Moving all backups to Backup server"
```

This will log the following:

```
18/01/2018 14:28:32 [LOG]: Starting backup procedure
18/01/2018 14:28:14 [LOG]: Dumping MongoDB databases
18/01/2018 14:28:14 [LOG]: connected to: localhost
18/01/2018 14:28:14 [LOG]: Moving all backups to Backup server
```

However, if I remove the `2>&1 | LogMsg` then the rest of the mongodump.sh is executed, and It spits out a lot more information in the shell:

```
root@Debian-81-jessie-64-LAMP:~# ./backupjobs.sh 
connected to: localhost
Thu Jan 18 14:28:41.204 DATABASE: example    to     /root/backups/MongoDB/2018/01/18/14:28:41/example
Thu Jan 18 14:28:41.205         example.system.indexes to /root/backups/MongoDB/2018/01/18/14:28:41/example/system.indexes.bson
Thu Jan 18 14:28:41.205                  16 objects
```

Comment: I can see a number of other problems, too. http://shellcheck.net/ picks up a couple, though there's a toxic mixture of additional smells here. Are you *really sure* you want to reinvent logging poorly again?

Comment: Whatever `mongodump.sh` is running, it's detecting whether its standard output is a terminal or not to adjust its output accordingly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The OP has a `read` command in his function; your link isn't relevant.

Comment: One suggestion is to just filter instead of trying to read: `if [ -n "$*" ]; then printf "%s [LOG]: %s\n" "$(date...)" "$*"; else sed -e "s@^@$(date ...) [LOG]@"; fi` but this whole approach is fragile.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The link doesn't have *any* command that reads from standard input. `date` will ignore standard input, leaving it for `read` to consume.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedbacks. Found a working solution for now by looping the read. But will take the feedbacks from you and clean it up some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LogMsg has only ONE read, and then ends, killing mongodump.sh.  LogMsg should loop until all has been read.